# How to empty all reply channel from group?

Tags: django, django-channels

I don't know which reply channels are in the Channel Group but I want to empty the group. How to do that?

Comment: Have you read the docs?

Comment: yep.  Are you reffering to group.discard(reply_channel)

Comment: I am referring to the docs in general =) Add what you have already tried to the question. People are more likely to help if you give details. Also less likely to downvote.

Comment: thanks for the advice

Comment: Good luck. If you can't figure out once you have tried a couple of things come back and ask again.